# three.js sphere with texture displayed in wrong way

Tags: three.js, textures

I use three.js to render room preview. When I move camera to look at the ceiling I see that the texture renders in wrong way.

This image shows what I see:
[image]

But I should see this:
[image]

What can be wrong in the code below:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
var loader = textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(150, 32, 32, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI);

leftSphere.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));
material.map = loader.load('image.jpeg');
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(sphere, material));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code, it's more like a general problem.

It very likely has to do with how the SphereGeometry is constructed. If you turn on the wireframes and look at the zenith you will see that there are a lot of very densely packed edges converging into a single point. I can't explain right now what exactly is happening but it looks like the sampled points from the texture are just too close together at that point.